# How did Slughorn know that Ginny would be "Slug Club material" other than a particularly good Bat-Bogey Hex?

Tags: harry-potter

She was a good wizard who could do a [hard spell.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102157/whats-so-special-about-the-bat-bogey-hex)

Yet, something tells me that Slughorn chose Ginny for her prodigious Quidditch skills, not as a wizard, as she does go play for the Holyhead Harpies.

So how did he know her prodigious Quidditch skills from that?

If that "something" is wrong, and Slughorn is easily impressed, then please give an answer that does not have anything to do with Blaise Zabini.

Comment: He likely chose her because she's the scion of a well-connected and noble pureblood family, and given her attractiveness, liable to end up marrying someone of wealth and connection.

Comment: @Valorum She is interesting just because of the man she may marry to? So Slughorn is not only racist, he is also sexist?

Comment: @oriol - Slughorn collects '*connections*". She might end up being someone important. She might end up marrying someone important. Either way that gives him influence.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's so special about the Bat-Bogey Hex?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102157/whats-so-special-about-the-bat-bogey-hex)

Comment: While related, neither of the answers to the proposed duplicate appear to answer this question (which for some reason involves a theory about Ginny's Quidditch skills and explicitly not Blaise Zabini).

Comment: @JasonBaker That question is about the Bat-Bogey Hex, but this one is asking what **else** was 'special' about Ginny from Slughorn's point of view. I can't see how it's a duplicate.

Comment: @JasonBaker I believe this site has been historically quite dupe happy, with answers being enough to make questions a dupe, but as far as I know the advice to people if their question isn't answered by an existing question is to start a new question, linking to the question that inspired it (instead of asking a new question in the answers, a common newbie error), which is precisely what was done here. I know I have a vested interest in this question, but I don't really think it would be fair to close it. as Rand says, that one is more interested in the spell, this one in the Slug Club

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Yet, something tells me that Slughorn chose Ginny for her prodigious
> Quidditch skills, not as a wizard,

Um, that seems to have come out of nowhere, I can't see what could have been taking place on the Hogwarts Express that would hint at Ginny's Quidditch talents. With all due respect, you seem to be proposing the theory and then asking us to find the supporting evidence for it!

The text says exactly why he chose her, good magic:

> 'How come you ended up in there, Ginny?'
>
> 'He saw me hex Zacharias Smith,' said Ginny, 'you remember that idiot from Hufflepuff who was in the DA? He kept on and on asking about what happened at the Ministry and in the end he annoyed me so much I hexed him - when Slughorn came in I thought I was going to get detention, but he just thought it was a really good hex and invited me to lunch! Mad, eh?'
>
> *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince* - p.141 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 7, *The Slug Club*

This seems to be supported by Slughorn's behaviour during the actual lunch:

> 'Oh dear!' chuckled Slughorn comfortably, looking round at Ginny who was glaring at Zabini around Slughorn's great belly. 'You want to be careful, Blaise! I saw this young lady perform the most marvellous Bat Bogey Hex as I was passing her carriage! I wouldn't cross her!'
>
> *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince* - p.139 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 7, *The Slug Club*

And this particular quote points to something else as well. Ginny is clearly quite feisty and presumably Slughorn saw that in her attack on Zacharias. Judging by his response - chuckling comfortably - to Ginny's outburst at Zabini, Slughorn rather enjoys that. Slughorn's whole thing is having a bit of an eye for a character, someone with a bit of charisma, a bit of a personality, a bit of spirit.

But *also* he makes mistakes, for example Marcus Belby. And with a lunch like this, he can afford to take a bit of a punt on someone like Ginny - in fact, that must surely be one of the means by which he collects the best people. He invites someone for lunch, sees how it goes; if it goes badly, they get missed out when the pies go round and don't seem to get invited back. But if it goes well, that's another box of crystallised pineapple.

Comment: Note - this intuition of his is correct. Fred and George specifically call Ginny out as being unusually powerful in Book 5. Quote follows. "Yeah, size is no guarantee of power," said George. "Look at Ginny."
"What d’you mean?" said Harry.
"You’ve never been on the receiving end of one of her Bat-Bogey Hexes, have you?"

Answer (score 0):

It's more likely that Slughorn chose her because he can read the newspapers.

Ginny was already famous in her own right.  She was boots-on-the-ground at the Ministry when the Death Eaters broke in, and like the other five gave as good an account of herself as many adult wizards would.

Answer (score -1):

While I don't disagree with Au101's answer and think it is probably correct, I might suggest there could be a secondary reason why Slughorn might have wanted to include Ginny in his Slug Club. I.e. Perhaps he thought by keeping Ginny close it would be a way to attract Harry.

This is NOT a canon answer by any means and why I think Au101 has the overall correct answer. But, having raised two sons and seeing them and their friends I have observed young boys/men often do things they would rather not simply because they want to stay in the company of a particular young girl/lady. That includes going out for sports in which they otherwise have no interest and, yes, even joining clubs they have previously said were 'stupid' because some young lady had joined it.

Given Slughorn's obvious social interaction with many of the young Hogwart's students, it certainly would not be out of the realm of possibility he could have learned of Ginny's attraction to Harry. Too, that he might intuit that Harry might someday return that attraction given his ongoing proximity to Ginny because Harry was obviously very close to the Weasleys. In particular as she was the only female born into the Weasely clan and had no other sisters to whom Harry might be attracted.

As Valorum noted in his comments:

*"He likely chose her because she's the scion of a well-connected and noble pureblood family, and given her attractiveness, liable to end up marrying someone of wealth and connection. – Valorum Oct 4 at 22:20"*